Accumulating tabular information from CSV file in a hook results in repeated rows
Please see the MWE below. I tried to collect the table rows in another command to circumvent the issue of not allowing tab (&) characters in the definition.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Students.csv}
  Key,Name,ID
  jod,John Doe,123
  jad,Jane Doe,456
\end{filecontents}

% Load the CSV file
\DTLloaddb{students}{Students.csv}

% Define a variable to store the accumulated information
\newcommand{\sinfo}{}

\newcounter{sn}
\setcounter{sn}{0}

% Define the \s macro to append the information to \sinfo using \gappto
\newcommand{\s}[1]{%
  % Try to fetch the values directly from the CSV database
  \DTLassignfirstmatch{students}{Key}{#1}{%
    \theName=Name,%
    \theID=ID}%
  % Increment the s counter and append row content
  \stepcounter{sn}
  \gappto{\sinfo}{%
    \arabic{sn}&%
    \theName&%
    \theID\tabularnewline\hline}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{List}

% Call the macro for each, information is collected in \sinfo
\s{jod}
\s{jad}

% Output the accumulated information
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Serial & Name & ID\\
    \hline
    \sinfo % Display the accumulated information
\end{longtable}

\end{document}

The program compiles fine. However, only the last row is repeated twice.

Use of xappto in place of gappto results in compilation errors.

! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.42 \s{jod}



Seems a few things need to be expanded before tokens are added to the replacement text of the macro \sinfo
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

% \usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Students.csv}
  Key,Name,ID
  jod,John Doe,123
  jad,Jane Doe,456
\end{filecontents}

% Load the CSV file
\DTLloaddb{students}{Students.csv}
% Define a variable to store the accumulated information
\newcommand{\sinfo}{}

\newcounter{sn}
% \setcounter{sn}{0}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup
  % Define the \s macro to append the information to \sinfo using \gappto
  \newcommand{\s}[1]{%
    % Try to fetch the values directly from the CSV database
    \DTLassignfirstmatch{students}{Key}{#1}{%
      \theName=Name,%
      \theID=ID}%
    % Increment the s counter and append row content
    \stepcounter{sn}%
    \protected@xappto{\sinfo}{%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\romannumeral`\^^@\arabic{sn}&}%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\theName&}%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\theID\tabularnewline\hline}%
    }%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\section{List}

% Call the macro for each, information is collected in \sinfo
\s{jod}
\s{jad}

% Output the accumulated information
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Serial & Name & ID\\
    \hline
    \sinfo % Display the accumulated information
\end{longtable}

\end{document}



How about wrapping things in \expanded and \unexpanded instead of accumulating replacement text of a macro?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}

% \usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Students.csv}
  Key,Name,ID
  jod,John Doe,123
  jad,Jane Doe,456
\end{filecontents}

% Load the CSV file
\DTLloaddb{students}{Students.csv}


\newcounter{sn}
% \setcounter{sn}{0}

% Define the macro \s to deliver a table row with the information 
% associated to the first record of the database "students" where the
% datafield "Key" has the value specified as the argument of \s:  
\newcommand{\s}[1]{%
  \unexpanded{%
    % Try to fetch the values directly from the CSV database
    %  - the assignment is global and thus applies in subsequent table cells, too:
    \DTLassignfirstmatch{students}{Key}{#1}{%
      \theName=Name,%
      \theID=ID%
    }%
    % Increment the s counter and append row content
    %  - the assignment is global and thus applies in subsequent table cells, too:
    \stepcounter{sn}%
    \arabic{sn}&\theName&\theID\tabularnewline
    \hline
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{List}

% Output the information contained in the database "students":
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Serial & Name & ID\\
    \hline
    \expanded{\s{jod}\s{jad}}%
\end{longtable}

\end{document}



Let's do some expl3 advertising:
If specifying a call to \s for each single "Key" whose associated data you wish to use seems cumbersome, you can provide a comma-list of "Keys" whereof each is "mapped" as argument to the macro \s by the expl3-function \clist_map_function:nN:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}

% \usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Students.csv}
  Key,Name,ID
  jod,John Doe,123
  jad,Jane Doe,456
\end{filecontents}

% Load the CSV file
\DTLloaddb{students}{Students.csv}


\newcounter{sn}
% \setcounter{sn}{0}

% Define the macro \s to deliver a table row with the information 
% associated to the first record of the database "students" where the
% datafield "Key" has the value specified as the argument of \s:  
\newcommand{\s}[1]{%
  \unexpanded{%
    % Try to fetch the values directly from the CSV database
    %  - the assignment is global and thus applies within subsequent table cells, too:
    \DTLassignfirstmatch{students}{Key}{#1}{%
      \theName=Name,%
      \theID=ID%
    }%
    % Increment the s counter and append row content
    %  - the assignment is global and thus applies within subsequent table cells, too:
    \stepcounter{sn}%
    \arabic{sn}&%
    \theName&%
    \theID\tabularnewline\hline%
  }%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \UseEachCommaListItemAsArgumentOfMacro #1#2
  {
    \clist_map_function:nN {#1}#2
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{List}

% Output the information contained in the database "students":
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Serial & Name & ID\\
    \hline
    \expanded{\UseEachCommaListItemAsArgumentOfMacro{jod, jad}{\s}}%
\end{longtable}

\end{document}



If you add \show\sinfo after the \xappto you will see
> \sinfo=macro:
->\arabic {sn}&\theName &\theID \tabularnewline \hline .
\s ...\theID \tabularnewline \hline }\show \sinfo 

so you are just adding (repeated) pointers to the data not the data itself so your final table has all rows looking the same,
Loops and expansion control are always easier using expl3 as that's what motivated its design but a simple fix here is
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Students.csv}
  Key,Name,ID
  jod,John Doe,123
  jad,Jane Doe,456
\end{filecontents}

% Load the CSV file
\DTLloaddb{students}{Students.csv}

% Define a variable to store the accumulated information
\newcommand{\sinfo}{}

\newcounter{sn}
\setcounter{sn}{0}

% Define the \s macro to append the information to \sinfo using \gappto
\newcommand{\s}[1]{%
  % Try to fetch the values directly from the CSV database
  \DTLassignfirstmatch{students}{Key}{#1}{%
    \theName=Name,%
    \theID=ID}%
  % Increment the s counter and append row content
  \stepcounter{sn}%
  \expanded{\noexpand\gappto{\noexpand\sinfo}{%
    \arabic{sn}&%
    \theName&%
    \theID\noexpand\tabularnewline\noexpand\hline}}%
  \show\sinfo
}

\begin{document}

\section{List}

% Call the macro for each, information is collected in \sinfo
\s{jod}
\s{jad}

% Output the accumulated information
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Serial & Name & ID\\
    \hline
    \sinfo % Display the accumulated information
\end{longtable}

\end{document}

which shows
> \sinfo=macro:
->1&John Doe&123\tabularnewline \hline .
\s ...ularnewline \noexpand \hline }}\show \sinfo 
                                                  
l.43 \s{jod}
            
? 
> \sinfo=macro:
->1&John Doe&123\tabularnewline \hline 2&Jane Doe&456\tabularnewline \hline .
\s ...ularnewline \noexpand \hline }}\show \sinfo 
                                                  
l.44 \s{jad}
            
? 

(remove the \show for production of course)
